# How to Change High Contrast Background Images using SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to make a mixin for standard background images and high contrasted background images, not sure how do i do it. can someone pl. shade some light

I have a mixin for text color and background color :

```
$colors:(
  standard: (
    primary-color-blue: #2aace2,
    mid-blue-color:#2695d2,
    dark-blue-color:#124b62
  ),
  contrasted: (
    primary-color-blue: #177eab,
    mid-blue-color:#1c6f9b,
    dark-blue-color:#124b62
  )
);


@function get-color($key, $type: 'standard'){
  @each $name, $color in map-get($colors, $type){
    @if($key == $name){
      @return $color
    }
  }
}

@mixin get-color($property,$color){
  #{$property}: get-color($color);
  @at-root body.contrasted & {
    #{$property}: get-color($color, contrasted);
  }
}


.className{
  @include get-color(background-color, primary-color-blue)
}
```

output :

```
.className {
  background-color: #2aace2;
}
body.contrasted .className {
  background-color: #177eab;
}
```

Thanks !!

EDITED AS PER ANSWER :  Edited with extra color / transparent variable, but throws error Edited with extra color / transparent variable, but throws error

```
$images:(
  standard: (
    pdp-more-icon-mob: white + $img_file_path + 'product-detail-page/Product-surface-display/more-icon/More-Mobile.png',
    pdp-more-icon-mob-retina :  #f00 + $img_file_path + 'product-detail-page/Product-surface-display/more-icon/More-Mobile__2x.png'
  ),
  contrasted: (
    pdp-more-icon-mob: green + $img_file_path + 'product-detail-page/Product-surface-display/more-icon/More-Desktop-High-Contrast.png',
    pdp-more-icon-mob-retina :  $green + $img_file_path + 'product-detail-page/Product-surface-display/more-icon/More-Desktop-High-Contrast__2x.png'
  )
);


@function get-images($key, $type: 'standard'){
  @each $name, $image in map-get($images, $type){
    @if($key == $name){
      @return $image
    }
  }
}

@mixin get-images($property, $color, $image, $retina:false){
  #{$property}: get-images($color + $image);
  @at-root body.contrasted & {
    #{$property}: get-images($color +  $image, contrasted);
  }
  @if($retina){
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
        #{$property}: get-images($color + $image#{-retina});
        @at-root body.contrasted & {
          #{$property}: get-images($color + $image#{-retina}, contrasted);
        }
     }
  }
}


.className{
  @include get-images(background, color, image, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without refactoring the mixin** is possible to use it this way—by adding your images properly in your map:

```
$colors:(
  standard: (
    primary-color-blue: #2aace2,
    mid-blue-color:#2695d2,
    dark-blue-color:#124b62,
    image: 'img.png',
    image-retina: 'img-retina.png'
  ),
  contrasted: (
    primary-color-blue: #177eab,
    mid-blue-color:#1c6f9b,
    dark-blue-color:#124b62,
    image: 'img2.png',
    image-retina: 'img2-retina.png'
  )
);


@function get-color($key, $type: 'standard'){
  @each $name, $color in map-get($colors, $type){
    @if($key == $name){
      @return $color
    }
  }
}

@mixin get-color($property,$color){
  #{$property}: get-color($color);
  @at-root body.contrasted & {
    #{$property}: get-color($color, contrasted);
  }
}


.className{
  @include get-color(background-image, image);
  @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
    @include get-color(background-image, image-retina)
  }
}
```

But you can also **adapt this mixin** for images and do so:

```
$images:(
  standard: (
    image: 'img.png',
    image-retina: 'img-retina.png'
  ),
  contrasted: (
    image: 'img2.png',
    image-retina: 'img2-retina.png'
  )
);


@function get-images($key, $type: 'standard'){
  @each $name, $image in map-get($images, $type){
    @if($key == $name){
      @return $image
    }
  }
}

@mixin get-images($property,$image, $retina:false){
  #{$property}: get-images($image);
  @at-root body.contrasted & {
    #{$property}: get-images($image, contrasted);
  }
  @if($retina){
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
        #{$property}: get-images($image#{-retina});
        @at-root body.contrasted & {
          #{$property}: get-images($image#{-retina}, contrasted);
        }
     }
  }
}


.className{
  @include get-images(background-image, image, true);
}
```

Where the true in 'get-images' is calling to image + '-retina' in the $images map, and outputs:

```
.className {
  background-image: "img.png";
}
body.contrasted .className {
  background-image: "img2.png";
}
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .className {
    background-image: "img-retina.png";
  }
  body.contrasted .className {
    background-image: "img2-retina.png";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
so do i need to add all the Background Images in standard and contrasted variables ? 
like this  > $images:(
  standard: (
    image-1: 'img.png',
    image-1-retina: 'img-retina.png',    image-2: 'img.png',
    image-2-retina: 'img-retina.png'
  ),
  contrasted: (
    image: 'img2.png',
    image-retina: 'img2-retina.png'
  )
);

Comment: Exactly, just make sure to add the same name in standard and contrasted, so: $images:( standard: ( image-1: 'img.png', image-1-retina: 'img-retina.png', ), contrasted: ( image-1: 'img2.png', image-1-retina: 'img2-retina.png' ) );

Comment: Pl. check my edited question, i need to also add color / transparent before img like > background : #fff url('img.png') no-repeat 10px 10px;

Comment: You already have got it, don't mix properties, instead, use the other mixin get-color(background-image, transparent) and put simply background-repeat: no-repeat.